# Mysql for a given group type get count and sum from other tables

Tags: mysql

I have two tables. users and transactions.lets say type 1 is student and type 2 is teacher

users:

```
+----+--------+--------------+
| id | name   | user_type_id |
+----+--------+--------------+
|  1 | Noob   |            1 |
|  2 | Coder  |            2 |
+----+--------+--------------+
```

transactions:

```
+----+---------+--------+
| id | user_id | amount |
+----+---------+--------+
|  1 |       1 |     10 |
|  2 |       2 |     10 |
|  3 |       1 |     10 |
+----+---------+--------+
```

I want to get the sum and count for each user_type_id;
Something like this

```
user_type_id:1 
sum_of_transaction: 20,
number_of_transactions: 2,

user_type_id:2
sum_of_transaction: 10,
number_of_transactions: 1
```

How can I do that? Noob here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select aa.user_type_id, sum(bb.amount) as sum_of_transaction,
       count(bb.id) as number_of_transactions 
from users aa inner join transactions bb on aa.id = bb.user_id 
group by aa.user_type_id
```

Answer (score 0):

For sum_of_transaction: `select sum(amount) as sum_of_transaction from transactions where user_id = ?;`

For number_of_transactions: `select count(amount) as number_of_transactions from transactions where user_id = ?;`